# How to make Rotate in WPF

Tags: wpf, animation

I beginner in wpf and I want rotate a TextBlock but I have error:"Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'RotateTransform.Angle'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties."

```
 <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Style="{StaticResource Rotate}">
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-16.308"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <TextBlock.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="image/1.png"></ImageBrush>
        </TextBlock.Background>
    </TextBlock>
```

and this is my style

```
<Style x:Key="Rotate"  TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <!--<Setter Property="Width" Value="10"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="10"></Setter>-->
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"></Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions >
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotateTransform.Angle" To="-360" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You *should* be able to use the orientation of a stack panel in your xaml to rotate easily, but this does not give immediate access to the angle.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Textbox ...../>
</StackPanel>
```

Or in your style you can add a setter property.

```
<Setter Property="RenderTransform">
     <Setter.Value>
         <RotateTransform Angle="-90"></RotateTransform>
     </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need TransformGroup in your RenderTransorm, then StoryboardTargetProperty will be look like

```
RenderTransform.Children[0].Angle
```

If you leave only RotateTransform there, then it will be

```
RenderTransform.Angle
```

In both cases, as you see, we start searching property from **RenderTransform**.